# How do download of Json using Fetch in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json, fetch

how do download of a JSON required from Fetch URL?

Download is in XLSX.

CODE

```js
function teste (){

alert(fetch ("url")        
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => { console.log(data)})
     .then(response => response.blob())
        .then(blob => {
            var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            var a = document.createElement('a');
            a.href = url;
            a.download = "filename.xlsx";
            a.click();                    
        })
)
}
```

Comment: What is purpose of `alert()`? No value is returned from second `.then()`

Comment: Well, for one thing, the first `.then()` isn't propogating the `data` which means the second `.then()`'s `response` is `undefined`.

Comment: For do a test, i don't know if is correct it is form.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `alert()`, `return` value from `.then()`. Note `Response` can only be read once

```
function teste() {   
  fetch("url")
    .then(async(response) => {
      let clone = response.clone();
      let res = await clone.json();
      console.log(res);
      return response.blob()
    })
    .then(blob => {
      var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      var a = document.createElement('a');
      a.href = url;
      a.download = "filename.xlsx";
      a.click();
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.error(err)
    })
}
```

Comment: @JeanCarlos Note, the dynamically created `<a>` element should be appended to `document.body` or other existing element in `DOM` as well for the code to render same result at Firefox. Chromium, Chrome launches `Save File` dialog without dynamically created `<a>` element having to be explicitly appended to a `document`.