# React fetch gives me a truncated JSON response

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, fetch

I'm facing an issue in React fetch, it gives me an incomplete response, so when I parse the response into JSON, it was returning me an error.

Code:

```
export default async (url, body = null, method = 'GET') => {
  let config = {
      method,
  };
  try {
      const response = await fetch(url, config);
      if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error(response.statusText);
      }
      return await response.json();
  } catch (error) {
      console.warn(error);
      throw error;
  }
};
```

Response log:
[image: Response log]

Does fetch has a maximum response size? If yes, how to increase it?

Answer (score 4):

There's no max limit to fetch response size.

The error in your case means that you are reading the response body more than once. Try guarding the `.json()` calls with `Body.bodyUsed`.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body

Comment: It's an async function so it will called more than once, isn't it? You mean, I need to validate whether `bodyUsed` was true or not on `.json()` call?

Comment: @JustinusHermawan See [Reread a response body from JavaScript's fetch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40497859/reread-a-response-body-from-javascripts-fetch/), [How do download of Json using Fetch in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46797810/how-do-download-of-json-using-fetch-in-javascript/)

Comment: @guest271314 I don't have any problem with `TypeErrror: already read`, it just because I'm debugging with `response.text()`, just ignore it.

My problem was in the truncated JSON response as I saw in `response.text()` log.

Comment: @JustinusHermawan `Response.body` can only be read once. `.json()` call reads the `ReadableStream` that is `Response.body`, see also [Why fetch Body object can be read only once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46742251/why-fetch-body-object-can-be-read-only-once/)

Comment: @JustinusHermawan _"My problem was in the truncated JSON response as I saw in `response.text()` log. "_ Did you expand the JavaScript object at the `console`?

Comment: @guest271314 Yes I did. It seems larger size while in Chrome dev tools. Sometimes it's completely (https://imgur.com/a/PpKse) but sometimes it's missing the last `}` bracket (https://imgur.com/a/4laG9).

Comment: Try `console.log(JSON.stringify(<JSON>), null, 2)`

Comment: There would probably be a parse error if the response was invalid `JSON` when passed to `JSON.stringify()`. Not certain what issue is?

Comment: @guest271314 But it always return completely when requesting from browser or postman.

Comment: @guest271314 Yes, it was error when I call `.json()`.